# Can't find Image class in System.Drawing under .NET Core 2.2

Tags: c#, image, .net-core

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image?view=netcore-2.2), there's supposed to be a class for thumbnail handling in the namespace `System.Drawing`. I want to create a model that has an image as a property and then save it to a database. However, when I try the code below, I get an error that the class isn't found in that namespace, regardless of the docs stating otherwise.

```
using System.Drawing;
public class Donkey
{
  public Image Image { get;set; }
}
```

What am I missing?!

I've googled it but only found [old posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40892189/net-core-and-system-drawing) and [examples that seem not to work](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/How-to-save-Image-to-978a7b0b).

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Try installing the `System.Drawing.Common` NuGet package. This contains `Image` and other related types like `Bitmap`.

```
PM> Install-Package System.Drawing.Common
```

You can also install using the NuGet Package Manager UI accessible by right-clicking the solution in **Solution Explorer** and choosing **Manage NuGet Packages...**

[image: System.Drawing.Common]

Adding a clarification comment from [**@KonradViltersten**](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1525840/konrad-viltersten):

> Traditionally, `System.Drawing` was included in the full .NET Framework,
>   but not .NET Core because `System.Drawing` was based on Windows drawing
>   methods. .NET core was designed to be platform independent and thus
>   did not include anything that was platform specific (like drawing).
>   Because this functionality is so requested, MS released a separate assembly that could be installed to provide the functionality

Comment: It seem rather random that *System.Drawing.Printing* is there by default but *System.Drawing.Image* needs to be nugotten (newgot? gotten by nuget? nugetgot?)... Also a clearer documentation of that would be of help.

Comment: Also, a quick validation of my assumption - that's the right class to manage images, right? I can store that junk using EF directly to the DB. Correct?

Comment: It's not that weird. System.Drawing.Common, like the description says, gives access to GDI+ graphics. This had to be rewritten from classic .net to .net core, and is not part of the .net core build but rather an extension since .net core is meant to be minimum necessary components. I can't speak for the .Printing namespace but this is absolutely correct.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch That was very well-worded. May I suggest that you copy in your comment as a paragraph of the accepted answer? It would make it even more great. And then we can remove the comments.

Comment: A link to the original Microsoft announcement will make it clear https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/11/16/announcing-the-windows-compatibility-pack-for-net-core/

Comment: Weird how I never had to include this package until dotnet 8. I am only using `System.Drawing.Image.FromStream` but have been happily doing without it for dotnet 7. Curious what happened, but adding it fixed everything.

Answer (score 1):

Since .NET 6 [`System.Drawing.Common` only supported on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only#recommended-action). Check out the [Recommended action](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/compatibility/core-libraries/6.0/system-drawing-common-windows-only#recommended-action) section of the doc for alternatives:

> To use these APIs for cross-platform apps, migrate to one of the following libraries:

> - [SkiaSharp](https://github.com/mono/SkiaSharp)
> - [ImageSharp](https://sixlabors.com/products/imagesharp) (tiered license)
> - [Microsoft.Maui.Graphics](/dotnet/maui/user-interface/graphics/)